# Why am I Receiving a Table Not Found Error for Saved Sqoop Jobs?

Tags: sqoop, amazon-emr, data-migration

I am using AWS EMR.
When I execute a saved sqoop job, I receive the following error:

```
Warning: /usr/lib/sqoop/../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
19/03/12 22:36:21 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.7
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/slf4j-log4j12- 
1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/hive/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl- 
2.6.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an 
explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
19/03/12 22:36:21 DEBUG tool.JobTool: Enabled debug logging.
19/03/12 22:36:22 DEBUG hsqldb.HsqldbJobStorage: Checking for table: 
SQOOP_ROOT
19/03/12 22:36:22 DEBUG hsqldb.HsqldbJobStorage: Found table: 
SQOOP_ROOT
19/03/12 22:36:22 DEBUG hsqldb.HsqldbJobStorage: Looking up property 
sqoop.hsqldb.job.storage.version for version null
19/03/12 22:36:22 DEBUG hsqldb.HsqldbJobStorage:  => 0
19/03/12 22:36:22 DEBUG hsqldb.HsqldbJobStorage: Looking up property 
sqoop.hsqldb.job.info.table for version 0
19/03/12 22:36:22 DEBUG hsqldb.HsqldbJobStorage:  => SQOOP_SESSIONS
19/03/12 22:36:22 DEBUG hsqldb.HsqldbJobStorage: Checking for table: SQOOP_SESSIONS
19/03/12 22:36:22 DEBUG hsqldb.HsqldbJobStorage: Found table:  
SQOOP_SESSIONS
19/03/12 22:36:22 DEBUG hsqldb.HsqldbJobStorage: Restoring job: myJob0
19/03/12 22:36:22 DEBUG hsqldb.HsqldbJobStorage: Job: myJob0; Getting 
properties with class schema
19/03/12 22:36:22 DEBUG hsqldb.HsqldbJobStorage: Job: myJob0; Getting 
properties with class SqoopOptions
19/03/12 22:36:22 DEBUG hsqldb.HsqldbJobStorage: Job: myJob0; Getting 
properties with class config
19/03/12 22:36:22 DEBUG hsqldb.HsqldbJobStorage: System property set: 
0
19/03/12 22:36:22 DEBUG hsqldb.HsqldbJobStorage: Stored property set: 
0
19/03/12 22:36:22 DEBUG util.SqoopJsonUtil: Passed mapJsonStr ::null 
to parse
--table or --query is required for import. (Or use sqoop import-all- 
tables.)
Try --help for usage instructions.
19/03/12 22:36:22 DEBUG hsqldb.HsqldbJobStorage: Flushing current 
transaction
19/03/12 22:36:22 DEBUG hsqldb.HsqldbJobStorage: Closing connection
```

Note: When I execute this command without creating a sqoop job then it works fine.
So, there is no possibility that I have missed table name or any syntax error.

When I check the saved sqoop job then I found that `db.table name` is missing from the Sqoop Metastore.

Please suggest to me How I can resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.